# change column style in a table shiny (R)

Tags: css, shiny

I am using shiny to show in an app a table with some results.  I would like to show two column with his content in other color or in bold. My code is the next one:

UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(
    HTML('
         body { 
         background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #25c481, #25b7c4);
         background: linear-gradient(to right, #25c481, #25b7c4);

         }
     h1{
     background-color: white;  
     }
     table{

     }
     ')
)),
  # This one is linked by the id 'download'
  downloadButton('download',"Descargar Predicciones"),
  fluidRow(column(7,dataTableOutput('dto')))
)
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input,output){
  # Reactive expression with the data, in this case iris

  output$dto <- renderDataTable({predictions})
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){"Predicciones_Consumo.csv"}, 
    content = function(fname){
      write.csv(predictions, fname)
    }
  )

}
```

I would like to change the appearence the 6th and 7th column

Cheers

Comment: `DT` makes it easy to create customizable tables in R/shiny https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html

Comment: thank you very much. Really good URL